# Can I change the Continue Shopping button by store?

Tags: magento-1.8, cart

Can I change the Continue Shopping button by store?  I want one store to link to an ETERNAL site whereas all others can link back to site home page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the button-link at the checkout-success-page?

The url is not changable by backend configuration.

Either you have to extend the template

```
app/design/frontend/[yourpackage]/[yourtheme]/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

by including this condition:

```
<?php if (Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() == 'your-store-code'): ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

or set a new template for the success-block in the layout xml file

app/design/frontend/[yourpackage]/[yourtheme]/layout/local.xml

```
...
<STORE_[store_code]>
    <reference name="checkout.success">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>[.*].phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</STORE_[store_code]>
...
```

Decide on your needs.

Comment: OK.  So am I right in thinking that I need to create a new template for that specific store checkout page and then call it in the layout file?  I am a newbie ... Can you please point me in the right direction for where to find these files?

Comment: > I am a newbie
So let's keep it simple, then.

Copy 
app/design/frontend/base/template/checkout/success.phtml
to
app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/template/checkout/success.phtml
and edit right there

Comment: How do I make sure that only the one store I want to be different is affected and not all the stores using the same theme?

Comment: I have edited the main answer.. hope it helps